# Laravel 5.8, URL rewrite without port

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, routes

I have a site running in docker and portainer on port 8018, and I'm binding a URL to it on a server so that I can visit `http://thissite.com` rather than `http://thissite.com:8018`

It seems like every page on it shows the correct url paths, except login and logout which the forms are still forcing the action url to be `http://thissite.com:8018/login`

I can inspect and remove the port which gets me around the issue and into the site but logout does the same thing.

Is there a laravel 5.8 configuration to proxy this without the port for the routes?

update:

so far I've tried `action="{{ url('login') }}"` and `action="{{ route('login') }}"`

Comment: You should post an excerpt from your blade file so we can see how the URLs are defined. Specifically, are you using a relative path `action="/login"` or a route `action="{{ route('login') }}"`?

Comment: @matticustard good point, I just posted the actions that i've tried (both route and url)

Comment: everything else in the site seems to work fine but they are using ajax calls and links that are relative for the most part

Comment: I get that you probably want to be able to use the helpers, but does `action="/login"` work?  It would at least eliminate a client side issue.

Comment: yes that does work actually

Comment: I added an answer.  I don't know if it solves all of your problems, but it should at least allow you to continue to use the `route()` helper.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the `route()` helper to return a url without the host (and port) by passing `false` or its equivalent as a third parameter.  This should at least allow you to continue to use route names instead of a static URL, if desired.

```php
{{ route('login',[],0) }} 
// '/login'
```

**Additional notes**

Both the `url()` and `route()` helpers create an absolute URL appending the host and apparently the port as well. I followed the `route()` helper to a method called `addPortToDomain()` which appears to automatically retrieve a port from the request data.  There is likely something similar going on for `url()`.

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteUrlGenerator.php**

```php
protected function addPortToDomain($domain)
{
    $secure = $this->request->isSecure();

    $port = (int) $this->request->getPort();

    return ($secure && $port === 443) || (! $secure && $port === 80)
                ? $domain : $domain.':'.$port;
}
```